# 0 hashrate - issue when mining Monero with CPUminer

Tags: cpu-mining, raspberry-pi

**Note:** I know there are some answers out there like but none of them solved my problem. I  also tried installing other miners but none of them worked for me (and I want to mine with CPUminer)...

I've installed CPUminer to mine Monero on my Raspberry Pi 3B (CPU: **ARM Cortex-A53 / ARMv8-A**) with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install autoconf libcurl4-openssl-dev libjansson-dev openssl libssl-dev gcc gawk

git clone https://github.com/lucasjones/cpuminer-multi.git

cd cpuminer-multi

sudo ./autogen.sh

sudo ./configure

sudo make
```

and ran it using:

```
minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45700 -u myMiningAccount@gmail.com -p x
```

the pools address and port are correct. I get an output like:

```
[2018-06-30 17:56:08] Using JSON-RPC 2.0
[2018-06-30 17:56:08] CPU Supports AES-NI: NO
[2018-06-30 17:56:08] Starting Stratum on stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45560
[2018-06-30 17:56:08] 4 miner threads started, using 'cryptonight' algorithm.
[2018-06-30 17:56:08] Binding thread 1 to cpu 1
[2018-06-30 17:56:08] Binding thread 2 to cpu 2
[2018-06-30 17:56:08] Binding thread 3 to cpu 3
[2018-06-30 17:56:08] Binding thread 0 to cpu 0
[2018-06-30 17:56:09] Pool set diff to 1063
[2018-06-30 17:56:09] Stratum detected new block
[2018-06-30 17:56:09] Stratum detected new block
[2018-06-30 17:56:09] thread 3: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:56:09] thread 0: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:56:09] thread 1: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:56:09] thread 2: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:56:39] thread 2: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:56:46] thread 1: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:56:57] thread 2: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:56:58] accepted: 0/1 (0.00%), 8.59 H/s at diff 1063 (booooo)
[2018-06-30 17:57:02] thread 0: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:57:03] thread 0: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:57:04] accepted: 0/2 (0.00%), 8.63 H/s at diff 1063 (booooo)
[2018-06-30 17:57:05] thread 3: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:57:45] thread 1: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:57:58] thread 0: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:57:58] thread 1: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:57:59] accepted: 0/3 (0.00%), 9.08 H/s at diff 1063 (booooo)
[2018-06-30 17:58:01] thread 2: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:58:05] thread 3: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:58:26] Pool set diff to 500
[2018-06-30 17:58:26] Stratum detected new block
[2018-06-30 17:58:26] thread 2: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:58:26] thread 3: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:58:26] thread 0: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:58:27] thread 1: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:58:59] thread 2: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:59:00] accepted: 0/4 (0.00%), 8.26 H/s at diff 500 (booooo)
[2018-06-30 17:59:16] Stratum detected new block
[2018-06-30 17:59:16] thread 2: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:59:16] thread 1: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:59:16] thread 3: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:59:16] thread 0: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:59:21] thread 3: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-30 17:59:21] accepted: 0/5 (0.00%), 7.75 H/s at diff 500 (booooo)
```

full output [here](https://myseries.lima-city.de/code/cpuMiner.log)

as you can see, my hashes won't be accepted as well... I am really frustrated of not seeing any results...

I think I've done something wrong during compiling (probably compiled for the wrong cpu architecture...) and need to set CFLAGS but I have no idea how to do so...

Has anyone experience with crypto currencies on the raspberry pi? Please help me solving this issue!

If anything is unclear please tell me.. I need this thing solved!

---

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a 3-4 year old miner.  The mining/hashing algo was changed in April (May?)  You are using the old and incorrect miner, thus bad shares.

Try:
https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/

(oh and minergate is a pool with a bad rep for scamming/stealing hashes, from what I've read.)
Quick update:  I couldn't get xmr-stak to compile easy enough.  but got xmrig to compile on a Raspberry Pi3 & and Orange Pi Zero.  Getting accepted hashes/shares.

```
apt-get install -y git build-essential cmake libuv1-dev libmicrohttpd-dev
git clone https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig.git
cd xmrig
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! But when I do the `apt-get install...` i get an error: `Unable to locate package libuv1-dev`

Comment: ran it with `apt-get install libuv-dev` but version is 0.10.. does this also work fine with v0.10?

Comment: Not sure.  My Pi3 is running Kali Linux and the Orange Pi Zero is running Armbian.  I suggest deleting the git fully and start over.  (gotta love how linux ignores the #1 reason for a computer: to make life *easier* :) )

Comment: Got it to compile on a Pi2 B, Raspbian, but not on a Pi BRaspbian.

Comment: everything worked well until make.. I get [this](https://www.myseries.lima-city.de/code/compilingError.txt) error (too long for comment)...

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Mining in the rpi0 is not possible (with xmrig) because there is no support for armv6 processors... So.. I followed your instructions and an error occurred while `make`.. So I ran the following command: `CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt" CXXFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt" cmake .. -DWITH_HTTPD=OFF && make VERBOSE=1` everything worked well... Using my pi0 for controlling now ;) Thanks for help...